# Keras, shapes are incompatible

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I made a keras classification model, and I have inputs with different lengths, so I'm using `train_on_batch`. And I'm getting a
 `ValueError: Shapes (1, 5) and (1, 36329, 5) are incompatible` .

Each input is a set of 2D points.

`X_train.shape >>> (2680,)` 
`X_train[0].shape >>> (36329, 2)` 
`X_train[5].shape >>> (40233, 2)`

For the output shape :

```
y_train.shape >>> (2680, 5)
# y_train[0] >>> array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

The full code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(array, classes_bi, test_size=0.33, random_state=69)
```

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(10000, activation='LeakyReLU'))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='LeakyReLU'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='LeakyReLU'))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
epochs=5
for epoch in range(5):
    for diag,output in zip(X_train,y_train):
        diag = np.expand_dims(diag,axis=0) #add the batch size = 1
        output = np.expand_dims(output,axis=0) ##add batch size = 1
        #print(diag.shape) >>> (1, 36329, 2)
        #print(output.shape) >>> (1, 5)
        model.train_on_batch(diag,output)
```

Error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_9248/1106303834.py in <module>
      6         print(diag.shape)
      7         print(output.shape)
----> 8         model.train_on_batch(diag,output)
...

ValueError: in user code:

...
   
ValueError: Shapes (1, 5) and (1, 36329, 5) are incompatible
```

I tried to expand the dimsention of output twice to get a shape of (1, 1, 5) with (1, 36329, 5)  but it didnt work.

Answer (score 2):

For the model you are building, the dimensions of your training data needs to be constant - it cannot vary from one training example to the other.

When you create a model with `Sequential()`, the input shape of your model will be defined when you do the training for the first time by calling `model.fit` or `model.train_on_batch`.

For example, if your first training batch has dimension (36329, 2), your model will assume that each of your training examples have the dimension (2, ) and this particular batch has 36329 training examples - so you need 36329 labels.

The batch size can change from batch to batch, but the dimension (2, ) needs to maintain.

**This might be your case:**

I think your problem is because your batch of 2D points contain thousands of examples but only 1 label per batch.

If each of the 36329 training examples in `X_train[0]` correspond to the same label `y_train[0] >>> array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0])`, all you need to do is broadcast the label so it has the same number of training examples as the input.

```
for epoch in range(5):
    for diag, output in zip(X_train,y_train):
        training_examples = diag.shape[0]
        broadcast_arr = np.ones((training_examples, 1))
        output = output * broadcast_arr
        model.train_on_batch(diag,output)
```

PS: I wanted to ask a couple of questions by commenting, but I don't have enough reputation to do so, that's why I'm posting this answer as my best understanding of your question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you can ask questions in your answer (then edit it after I answer you). I dont think your solution will work (I mean th code will work but the concept isn't what I want), because if I did that it will mean that each point has a class, while for me its the set of points that has a class and not each of them individually.

Comment: for example diag1= [[0,1],[1,2],[2,2]] has a target [0, 0, 0, 1, 0] and diag2= [[0,1],[5,6]] has a target [1, 0, 0, 0, 0] . If we applied your solution [0,1] will have target [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]  (from diag1) and also [1, 0, 0, 0, 0] (from diag2). Also conceptually the problem is to classify the sets of points, no the points. I will try it though and see how does it perform.

Comment: I see, this is what I was suspecting. The problem is that this simple feed-forward neural network won't do the job because it has a fixed input shape. As I mentioned in the answer, for this Sequential model, the input shape is determined when the first training example goes through the NN, then it expects the same shape for the following examples. You will need a more complex model to handle different shapes of training examples. Can you please share a little bit more about the problem you are trying to solve? That will help to identify the appropriate NN architecture for your model.

Comment: The problem is the classification of persistence diagrams. [Persistence diagrams](https://gudhi.inria.fr/python/latest/persistence_graphical_tools_user.html) is a way to extract topological features from data and instead of classifiying the data directly we classify the diagram of each data. If you want I can share the full code on my github project but I dont want to waste to waste your time as it's something too specefic.